# Only the first View recognizes a touchevent

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have multiple `ImageViews` on my screen. Whenever the user moves his finger over one or multiple of them, I want the ones the finger touched, to do something.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // do something
    foo()
    return false;
}
```

Why is only the first ImageView executing `foo()` but all ImageViews the finger touches afterwards (without lifting off the screen) do not recognize a touch event.

Comment: just `return true`

Comment: I delete my View and create a new one, if I return `true` the same touchlistener is called again and tries to remove the already removed view a second time. Anyway I will start a new question with more details, as this question was just about propagating the touch event on. Thansk anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same touch listener is called multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168601/same-touch-listener-is-called-multiple-times)