# Same touch listener is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have multiple ImageViews on my screen. Whenever the user moves his finger over one or multiple of them, I want the ones the finger touched, to be removed and create new ImageViews.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    createNewImageViews();
    return true;
}
```

The problem is, that my app crashes. I think the reason is, that a touchlistener is called again, that already deleted its view and tries to delete it again.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

What should I do to make it working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are confused at the start line :)

#### Some explanation.

When Android catch TouchEvent, he dispatch him to root element, and root in his turn - dispatch to all childs recursively, thought view tree, until some view signalize that touch event is processed, and no one view can handle this event.

#### So.

If you need to dispatch TouchEvent from one View to Another you should jumping up to one level and dispatch from there.

#### Diagram

[image]

You should set `setOnTouchListener` to parent `ViewGroup` and throw forward to his children.

Comment: I'm not that experienced, can you give me any examples of how to achieve this?

Comment: @Jonas see diagram

Comment: After some research I'm still struggling how to implement this. Can you post any code example?

Answer (score 0):

**In the below, I'm trying to get screen coordinates when touched on screen. The reason being it's called multiple times is when you touch the screen it goes under Motionevent.ACTION_DOWN and when you release your finger after touch it goes to Motionevent.ACTION_UP, and if you're not specifying the touch action then this may issue arise.**

```
binding.ivStory.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener{
        override fun onTouch(p0: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            val x = event?.x
            vak y = event?.y

            when (event!!.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->{
            //Do your stuff
                if (x != null) {
                }
             }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN  -> {

                }
            }
            return true
        }

    })
```

To handle such situation include at least these two scenarios, ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN and implement your logic in one of these.